# Why does Symfony look for "addWooklyExercise()" instead of "addWeeklyExercise()"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I changed, by client requirement,  an entity textfield (weekly_exercise) to a 1:n relation. Everything works normally so far, but when trying to save the form Symfony looks out for a "changed" method name.

That's the error message I get

```
Neither the property "weekly_exercise" nor one of the methods "addWooklyExercise()"/"removeWooklyExercise()", "setWeeklyExercise()", "weeklyExercise()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "XXX\CourseBundle\Entity\Course".
```

Of course `"addWooklyExercise()"/"removeWooklyExercise()"` don't exist. I could put them in and proxy to the real methods, but that would only be an ugly hack.

I've been looking through all my files and couldn't find a anything that could be responsible for this issue.

I'm on Symfony 2.5.7 as my client doesn't allow me to update!!

Files involved in the issue https://gist.github.com/mhauptma73

EDIT:

For some reason the method

```
public function addWooklyExercise(\BDA\CourseBundle\Entity\CourseWeeklyExercise $weeklyExercise)
{

    $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'addWooklyExercise', array($weeklyExercise));

    return parent::addWooklyExercise($weeklyExercise);
}
```

is being added in the cache proxy. But there is also the correctly spelled method, before the misspelled one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the naming convention like when you add the property for oneToMany then it's plural and for add or remove method change it to singular.

```
protected $tags;

public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{
    //...
}

public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
{
    // ...
}
```

See more details read this doc: 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/form_collections.html#form-collections-new-prototype

Comment: Might be a good idea convention-wise, but it won't solve my issue as the parameters are send correctly. Am I wrong?

Comment: I finally opted to change the naming and implemented it convention-wise. whether it was changing the name or the convetion, but the issue went away :-)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you have a typo somewhere, probably <s>your Entity,</s> your Form-Type or when outputting a form in a template. Try doing a search over the whole src/ directory for `wookly` and you will probably find it.

Comment: Did you check in the templates as well? Did you have case matching enabled, i.e. did you also check for Wookly or WOOKLY?

Comment: I disabled case mathing to be sure and looked through both php and twig files.I also checked the POST parameters that are being sent and they look the way they should.

Comment: In your entity you could temporarily create the getter and setter for wooklyExcercise and then try to find the usages. It's a long shot, but maybe that will bring up the wrong access

Comment: That worked... but how to I get now to know where the real problem occurs?

Comment: PhpStorm has a Find Usage function in the dropdown menu when you right click on the function name: http://imgur.com/a/b0AjH

Comment: I'm downloading phpstorm in case it can help me :-)

Comment: No Usages found :-(